# Not able to retrieve php cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to create a php cookie using 
`setcookie('usrid', $user_id, time()+3600);`

When I checked this with the browser, the cookie is set with the correct value passed with the variable. But I couldn't retreive the value using `$_COOKIE['usrid']`

I tried to delete the cookie using `setcookie("usrid", "", time()-3600);`, 
but its not getting deleted.

Now when I try to get the value of cookie, it shows the value.
Can anyone tell why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure `$user_id` actually stores a value? What does `var_dump($_COOKIE);` show?

Comment: The most common error is to use `setcookie` and then immediately try to use `$_COOKIE`. When  you setcookie (or delete a cookie), it takes effect on the NEXT page load. So, you cannot use it until the user comes back to the website. The "fix" is to immediately follow a setcookie by actually setting the value in $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

The path parameter was missing in setcookie function. When I set the path to "/", it worked.

Why it didn't work before is that I didn't provide the path parameter, so the cookie was only accessible from the path it was created. By setting the path parameter as "/", the cookie is accessible from any path of the domain.

Below is the code.

```
setcookie('usrid', $user_id, time()+3600, "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Set Cookie
2. Reload page
3. Read Cookie

Answer (score 0):

Check your php version, do something like this to get the value in your cookie:

$getCookie = ((int)phpversion() >= 5) ? $_COOKIE['usrid']  :   $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["usrid"];